# Is Excel Alt+Enter same as Newline character \n ?

Tags: java, excel

I am loading data from excel column which contain multiple lines separated by alt+enter. can i use the new line \n in java to match this alt+enter in data loaded from the cells during validation? is alt+enter in excel same as \n ?

Comment: This should be quite trivial to find out: just fetch the info and check what is in the spot of the `Alt-Enter`. My guess would be that it is [CR]-[LF], so `\r\n`.

Comment: This would be Chr(10) in Excel I believe which is the same as doing Alt + Enter in a cell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation of excel say that alt+enter puts char(10).
char(10) is Line-Feed (LF), so it is the same character as \n in java.

\r (CR) and \n (LF), are named after the typewriter actions of pulling the page carriage back to the start and scrolling it up a line.

Answer (score 1):

`Alt+Enter` in Excel is equivalent to `CR+LF` in Windows Format. We can check by copying the required text from Excel Cell (containing `Alt+Enter`) in Notepad++ (check the below snapshot)

Snapshot from Notepad++:

[image: Snapshot from Notepad++]

In Excel, `Alt+Enter` is a Line Break character equivalent to `Chr(10)`

Comment: You seem to contradict yourself: "Alt+Enter in Excel is equivalent to CR+LF in Windows Format." and "In Excel, Alt+Enter is a Line Break character equivalent to Chr(10)". Please make your answer more clear.